# Rails 3- Handling a conditional Create in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my def create controller:

```
@photo = current_user.photos.create(params[:photo].merge(:project_id => params[:project_id])
```

In my app photo records are valid if they have a project_id or not....

But I need my create statement not to error and work for both cases.
A. If there is a param project_id, insertit
B. If not, insert the default NULL value when creating the record

What's the smartest Rails3 way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => PROJECT_ID_WHICH_CAN_BE_NULL_OR_NOT %>
```

inside your view, in the photo form. The controller would then be:

```
@photo = current_user.photos.create(params[:photo])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an ActiveRecord validation in place, the create method should not raise if a column is nil.